# Monitor with USB Hub for two computers

Tags: usb, monitors, kvm, thunderbolt, display-port

I started working from home, and would like to have a convenient way to connect my work laptop to my desktop setup. That is a mouse, keyboard and one monitor. Preferably I would just need to plugin a USB-C to my laptop and get going. After some research, it seems like the easiest thing would be to buy a monitor connect everything through that.

Is this possible to do? I'm afraid that sharing mouse/keyboard will be a bit wonky.

I've read that some monitors have a build in KVM-switch, and I am not sure why that would be needed if displayport and usb-c can transfer everything I need. I feel a bit out of the loop because of this.

A solution that supports daisychaining monitor would be great (possibly buying another monitor in the future).

Currently I'm looking at these:

https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/curved/43-cj890-super-ultra-wide-curved-monitor-lc43j890dknxza/#specs

https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-ultrasharp-34-curved-usb-c-monitor-u3419w/apd/210-arcl/monitors-monitor-accessories

https://www.dell.com/ae/business/p/dell-s2718d-monitor/pd

https://www.lenovo.com/se/sv/accessories-and-monitors/monitors/professional/P27h-10A16270QP127inch-Monitor-HDMI/p/61AFGAT1EU

Any feedback on why these would/would not work is appreciated. Suggestions on other monitors and

Comment: Just answered an effectively identical question. If that doesn't cover what you need, explain why and @ me and I'll go ahead and re-open this question.

Comment: As for why daisy-chaining doesn't work, it just not really how the interface works. You can't just pass the laptop's connection through the desktop, just doesn't work that way. A KVM is the right way to go.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I looked at your answer, but couldnt comment as my reputation was too low. So Philips 346B1C would not support daisychaining? It would be great if I could hook up a new monitor to the setup in the future. @JMY1000

Comment: Individual monitors can support daisy-chaining; however, what exactly this behavior constitutes depends on the implementation of the monitor. Sometimes this will simply mean the ability to clone to another output, however if you want the ability to display properly on another monitor in full, you'll need a monitor that supports DisplayPort MST.

Comment: Ok, do you happen to have any suggestions? They four you linked in the previous post only had one DP, so if I understand correctly that would not work.
Or perhaps do you know where a good site to search for this? Googling for this has been quite a hassle. Something like a updated list with monitors that has built in KVM would be fantastic.@JMY1000

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. If this is a critical feature I can reopen this question, but otherwise, the answer is just that you'll have to give up some feature or use a series of hubs.